# Move directory using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to cut a folder. I've tried directoy.move(string source,string dest) & directoryinfo.moveto(dest) but in both case an exception was thrown "Source and destination path must have identical roots. Move will not work across volume".

Answer (score 2):

You cannot move files and folders across different volumes with `Directory.Move`. You have to create the directory at the destination, recursively copy the files across then, on success, delete the files at the source or, as Tim suggested in the comments below, recursively create the directory structure then move the files across with `File.Move`.

Comment: You can use [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx) with all files of the directory. This method works across volumes (see remarks).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't as specific as I hoped, I meant with `Directory.Move`.

Comment: Now you've lost me.  OP has tried `Directory.Move` which does not work across volumns (as you've stated correctly) but you don't need to copy from a to b, then delete the old files. You can use `File.Move` instead which does both and works across volumns (as opposed to `Directory.Move`).

Comment: My answer said that you CAN'T use `Directory.Move` due to the fact it doesn't work across volumes, so I suggested using copy/paste instead. I assumed your first comment was to do with the fact I just said Move instead of `Directory.Move` instead of providing a more efficient way of moving the individual files.

Comment: We're talking past each other ;) I don't know if it's more efficient, but it's shorter and maybe more readable. However, it was just a suggestion for a small improvement.

Comment: Thanx, but i'm actually moving file from one computer to another computer they lied on same network if i do file.move it is taking ages to copy 200 or more files.

Comment: I doubt there IS a faster way using C#, sorry!